# replace number from the middle using javascript / node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
var str = "demo-test-1-0-4_testing.pdf";
```

I have a string i want to replace with word `verified`

so my expected value look like this

```
str= demo-test-verified_testing.pdf
```

I can do this if the numbers are written in last like this

```js
var str = "demo-test-1-0-1";

str = str.replace(/(?!(-| |_))(\d|-|\.)+\s*$/, "verified");

console.log(str);
```

but in middle I don't know
as my expected value is like this `demo-test-verified_testing.pdf` as i want to replace `1-0-1` i can use replace function but every time version get updated so number get changed that's why i cant use replace function

Comment: Please describe exactly what would be replaced, providing a few examples, so we can be absolutely sure that your question is properly understood. At the moment, replacing `1-0-4` with `verified` is all we have to go on. There will be a lot of guesswork in the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be enough:

```js
var str = "demo-test-1-0-4_testing.pdf";
str = str.replace(/(-\d+)+/,"-verified")
console.log(str)

str = "demo-test-1-0-1"

str = str.replace(/(-\d+)+/,"-verified")
console.log(str)

var str = "demo-test-1-0-41_testing.pdf";
str = str.replace(/(-\d+)+/,"-verified")
console.log(str)
```

Comment: This ignores the alternations (e.g. `(-| |_)` ) in the question's example code.

Comment: @spender which possibly is ignorable, hence the question of whether it is ok what I did

Comment: thank you @mplungjan its working :) exactly what i want

Comment: no its fine i was using that in other function i just copied that regex here :)